# spring cloud config server reading only from master branch

Tags: java, spring, git, config, spring-cloud-config

Hey so I am trying to launch spring cloud config server on branch other then master. using following variables to setup:

```
git.local.uri = file:///${user.home}/config_repos/${spring.application.name}
spring.cloud.config.allowOverride = true
spring.cloud.config.allowOverrideNone = true
```

now to make sure config server reads from git branch `foo` I am using this:

```
spring.cloud.config.label = foo(_)
```

after this when I try to see config.yaml it is still showing `label: master`

all config files are in root of repo i-e no dir and sub dir inside repo just config files.

Answer (score 2):

`spring.cloud.config.label` can be used to define branch from client side. To define default branch on server side, you should use `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label`

Comment: I have tried above variables with `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label = foo` and then `spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label = foo(_)` both showing that files are still pulling from master: here is how
`"name": "file:////root/config_repos/config-service/master/test-service.yml#qa`
it is showing `master ` where it should be `foo/`

Comment: It's working for me. I'm using `Finchley.RELEASE` of `spring-cloud-starter-parent`. Which version are you using? Also, can you add your updated property files?